# jQuery change opacity of pictures

Tags: jquery, fadeto

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 jQuery(function ($) {
  
   // filter selector
    $(".filter").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // if we click the active tab, do nothing
        if ( !$this.hasClass("active") ) {
            $(".filter").removeClass("active"); 
            $this.addClass("active"); // set the active tab
            // get the data-rel value from selected tab and set as filter
            var $filter = $this.data("rel"); 
            // if we select view all, return to initial settings and show all
          if ($filter == 'all') { // if we select "view all", return to initial settings and show all
        $(".fancybox")
          .attr("data-fancybox-filter", "gallery")
          .fadeTo("fast", 1); // otherwise
      } else {
        $('.fancybox[data-filter="'+$filter+'"]') // select all items with the current filter
          .attr("data-fancybox-filter", $filter) // set the data-fancybox-group
          .fadeTo("fast", 1); // make them go "solid"
        $('.fancybox[data-filter!="'+$filter+'"]') // select all items not in the current filter
          .fadeTo("slow", 0.5); // fade them out partially
      } // filter if
    } // active if
  }); // on

    // fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        modal: false, // enable regular nav and close buttons
        // add buttons helper (requires buttons helper js and css files)
  padding:0,
        helpers: {
            thumbs : {
    width : 50,
    height : 50,
   },
        } 
    });
   
}); // ready
 
</script>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Qyas Engineering Consultancy</title>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Qyas Engineering Consultancy</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap stylesheet -->
  <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- sheet style -->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!-- include jquery -->
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- javscript jQuery -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

  <!-- fancybox -->
  <!-- fancybox jquery  -->
  <script src="js/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery easing -->
  <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <!-- fancybox stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/Fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <!-- fancybox javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
  <!-- fancybox buttons stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <!-- fancybox buttons javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
  <!-- fancybox media javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
  <!-- fancybox media stylesheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
  <!-- fancybox thumbs javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

  <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
  <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>


  <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container" id="project">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#defaultNavbar1" aria-expanded="false"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="defaultNavbar1">
          <a href="index.html"><img src="images/Office Logo.jpg" width="45" height="90" alt="" /></a>
          <a href="index.html"></a>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="careers.html">Careers</a></li>
            <li></li>
            <li><a href="contact_us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="index.html"></a>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div id="galleryTab">
      <a data-rel="all" href="javascript:;" class="filter active">All Projects</a>
      <a data-rel="vil" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Villas</a>
      <a data-rel="res" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Residential and Commercial</a>
      <a data-rel="mix" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Mixed Used</a>
      <a data-rel="port" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Previous Projects</a>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="galleryWrap" class="cf">

        <!--First Row Start -->
        <div class="row" style="height: 460px;">

          <div class="col-md-3" style="height: 460px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 5px;">
            <!-- P17 Mixed Use (Previous Projects) -->
            <a title="P17 Mixed Use-Dubai" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port5" href="images/Projects/P17 Mixed Use/p17 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/p17 1s.jpg" alt="p17" width="240" height="450" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 1px; display: block"></a>
            <div class="hidden">
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port5" href="images/Projects/P17 Mixed Use/p17 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/P17 Mixed Use/p17 2.jpg" alt="p17"></a>
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port5" href="images/Projects/P17 Mixed Use/p17 3.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/P17 Mixed Use/p17 3.jpg" alt="p17"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-left: -32px">
            <div class="row" style="height: 225px;">
              <!-- Omran villa -->
              <a title="Mr.Omran Villa (G+1+R)" class="fancybox" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/1s.jpg" alt="omran" width="350" height="220" style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; display: block"></a>
              <div class="hidden">
                <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/1h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/1h.jpg" alt="omran"></a>
                <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/12h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/12h.jpg" alt="omran"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Saif villa -->
            <div class="row" style="height: 225px;">
              <a title="Mr.saif Villa (G+1+R)" data-tags="Villas" class="fancybox" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/2s.jpg" alt="saif" width="350" height="220" class="img-responsive" style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top:5px; display: block"></a>
              <div class="hidden">
                <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/21h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/21h.jpg" alt="saif"></a>
                <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/22h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/22h.jpg" alt="saif"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Yonge st. (Previous Projects) -->
          <div class="col-md-4" style="height: 460px; margin-left: -40px; margin-right: 0px;">
            <a title="625 Yonge st.-Toronto" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port2" href="images/Projects/yonge/yonge 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/yonge 1s.jpg" alt="yonge" width="240" height="450" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 0px; display: block"></a>
            <div class="hidden">
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port2" href="images/Projects/yonge/yong 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/yonge/yong 2.jpg" alt="yonge"></a>
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port2" href="images/Projects/yonge/yonge 3.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/yonge/yonge 3.jpg" alt="yonge"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--Second Row Start -->
        <div class="row" style="height: 460px; margin-top: 5px;">
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="row" style="height: 225px;">
              <!-- Split Tower (Previous Projects) -->
              <a title="Split Tower-Dubai" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port3" href="images/Projects/SplitTower/split 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/split 1s.jpg" alt="split" width="350" height="220" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left;  display: block"></a>
              <div class="hidden">
                <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port3" href="images/Projects/SplitTower/split 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/SplitTower/split 2.jpg" alt="split"></a>
                <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port3" href="images/Projects/SplitTower/split 3.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/SplitTower/split 3.jpg" alt="split"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height: 225px;">
              <!-- Hilton Resort Rak (Previous Projects) -->
              <a title="Hilton Resort - RAK" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port4" href="images/Projects/RAK/rak 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/rak 1s.jpg" alt="split" width="350" height="220" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; display: block"></a>
              <div class="hidden">
                <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port4" href="images/Projects/RAK/rak 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/RAK/rak 2.jpg" alt="split"></a>
                <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port4" href="images/Projects/RAK/rak 3.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/RAK/rak 3.jpg" alt="split"></a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4" style="margin-left: -25px;">
            <!-- Ajman Tower (Buildings) -->
            <a title="Ajman Tower (G+8Podium+26 Typical+R)" class="fancybox" data-tags="Residential and Commercial" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/4.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/4s.jpg" alt="ajman" width="240" height="450" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; display: block"></a>
            <div class="hidden">
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/41h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/41h.jpg" alt="ajman"></a>
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/42h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/42h.jpg" alt="ajman"></a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Cumberland (Previous Projects) -->
          <a title="8 Cumberland-Toronto" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port1" href="images/Projects/Cumberland/cumber 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/cumberland 1s.jpg" alt="cumber" width="240" height="450" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-left: -120px; display: block "></a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port1" href="images/Projects/Cumberland/cmber 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Cumberland/cmber 2.jpg" alt="cumber"></a>
            <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port1" href="images/Projects/Cumberland/cumber 3.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Cumberland/cumber 3.jpg" alt="cumber"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Third Row Start -->
      <div class="row" style="height: 460px; margin-top: 5px;">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <!-- Seef Tower (Previous Projects) -->
          <a title="Seef Tower - Manama" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port6" href="images/Projects/Seef Tower/seef 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/seef 1s.jpg" alt="seef" width="240" height="450" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-left: 0px; display: block "></a>
          <div class="hidden">
            <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port6" href="images/Projects/Seef Tower/seef 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Seef Tower/seef 2.jpg" alt="seef"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <!-- Seef Tower (Previous Projects) -->
          <a title="Golden Falcon - Abu Dhabi" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port7" href="images/Projects/Golden Tower/golden 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/golden 1s.jpg" alt="golden" width="240" height="450" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-left: -135px; display: block "></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <div class="row" style="height: 225px;margin-left: -150px">
            <!-- Hydra Square (Previous Projects) -->
            <a title="Hydra Square - Abu Dhabi" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port8" href="images/Projects/Hydra/hydra 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/hydra 1s.jpg" alt="hydra" width="350" height="220" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-left: -120px; display: block "></a>
            <div class="hidden">
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port8" href="images/Projects/Hydra/hydra 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Hydra/hydra 2.jpg" alt="hydra"></a>
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port8" href="images/Projects/Hydra/hydra 3.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Hydra/hydra 3.jpg" alt="hydra"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" style="height: 225px;">
            <!-- Keneth Shepard (Previous Projects) -->
            <a title="Shepard and Keneth - Toronto" class="fancybox" data-tags="Previous Projects" data-filter="port" rel="port9" href="images/Projects/Keneth/keneth 1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Thumbnails/keneth 1s.jpg" alt="keneth" width="350" height="220" class="img-responsive" border="0" style="float: left; margin-left: -255px;margin-top: 5px; display: block "></a>
            <div class="hidden">
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port9" href="images/Projects/Keneth/keneth 2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Keneth/keneth 2.jpg" alt="keneth"></a>
              <a class="fancybox" data-filter="port" rel="port9" href="images/Projects/Keneth/keneth 3.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/Keneth/keneth 3.jpg" alt="keneth"></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <footer id="footeri">&copy;2017 QYAS Engineering Consultancy - All Rights Reserved. </footer>
  </div>
```

i have the below code where it filter my gallery according to category i click on... but i want not to fade out the other pictures i just want to change opacity of them i tried to replace `fade out()` function with `fade to()` function but it didn't work so can anyone help me with that

```js
 $(".filter").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // if we click the active tab, do nothing
        if ( !$this.hasClass("active") ) {
            $(".filter").removeClass("active");
            $this.addClass("active"); // set the active tab
            // get the data-rel value from selected tab and set as filter
            var $filter = $this.data("rel"); 
            // if we select view all, return to initial settings and show all
            $filter == 'all' ? 
                $(".fancybox")
                .attr("data-fancybox-filter", "gallery")
                .not(":visible")
                .fadeIn() 
            : // otherwise
                $(".fancybox")
                .fadeTo("slow", 0.4)
                .filter(function () {
                    // set data-filter value as the data-rel value of selected tab
                    return $(this).data("filter") == $filter; 
                })
                // set data-fancybox-group and show filtered elements
                .attr("data-fancybox-filter", $filter)
                .fadeIn(1000); 
        } // if
    }); // on
}); // ready
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `fadeTo`, but the use of `fadeIn` at the end assumes the items had been previously `fadeOut`ed. So instead, we use `fadeTo` to set the items we want back to full opacity.

The code for the snippet is modified from the [demo page here](http://www.picssel.com/demos/fboxfilteredgallery.html).

**Update**: Rather than chaining the fade out and the fade in with a filter function, i assume you would prefer them to happen concurrently. So I have modified the filter select code.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
    modal: true,
    helpers: {
      buttons: {}
    }
  });
  $(".filter").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    // if we click the active tab, do nothing
    if (!$this.hasClass("active")) {
      $(".filter").removeClass("active");
      $this.addClass("active"); // set the active tab
      var $filter = $this.data("rel"); // get the data-rel value from selected tab and set as filter
      if ($filter == 'all') { // if we select "view all", return to initial settings and show all
        $(".fancybox")
          .attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery")
          .fadeTo("fast", 1); // otherwise
      } else {
        $('.fancybox[data-filter="'+$filter+'"]') // select all items with the current filter
          .attr("data-fancybox-group", $filter) // set the data-fancybox-group
          .fadeTo("fast", 1); // make them go "solid"
        $('.fancybox[data-filter!="'+$filter+'"]') // select all items not in the current filter
          .fadeTo("slow", 0.2); // fade them out partially
      } // filter if
    } // active if
  }); // on
}); // ready
```

```css
.imgContainer {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 0;
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #999;
  display: block;
}

.imgContainer:hover {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #444;
  border-left: solid 1px #444;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px 1px #777;
  -moz-box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px 1px #777;
  box-shadow: -3px 3px 10px 1px #777;
  margin: 9px 19px 11px 1px;
}

#galleryTab {
  margin: 10px 5px 20px 0;
  top: 26px;
  width: 450px;
}

.galleryWrap {
  padding: 0 0 30px;
}

.filter {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #333333;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.filter:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 1px #a3a3a3;
  -moz-box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 1px #a3a3a3;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 5px 1px #a3a3a3;
  margin: -1px 11px 1px 1px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #aaa;
  border-left: solid 1px #aaa;
}

.filter.active {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #000;
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://picssel.com/demos/demos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://picssel.com/scripts/fancybox2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://picssel.com/scripts/fancybox2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.picssel.com/scripts/fancybox2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.picssel.com/scripts/fancybox2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>

<div id="wrap" class="cf">
  <h2>Create a filtered image gallery (Isotope style) with Fancybox and jQuery [DEMO]</h2>
  <div id="galleryTab" class="cf">
    <a data-rel="all" href="javascript:;" class="filter active">View all</a>
    <a data-rel="anim" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Animals</a>
    <a data-rel="land" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Landscapes</a>
    <a data-rel="arch" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Architecture</a>
  </div>
  <div class="galleryWrap cf">
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/architecture/lorenteJerome_barcelona.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='arch'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/lorenteJerome_barcelona.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/lorenteJerome_barcelona.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/landscape/sarahKlockars_aquatic.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/sarahKlockars_aquatic.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/sarahKlockars_aquatic.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/johnEllingsworth_opossum.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/johnEllingsworth_opossum.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/johnEllingsworth_opossum.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/landscape/miroslavVajdic_winter.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/miroslavVajdic_winter.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/miroslavVajdic_winter.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/architecture/erikaMlejova_malta.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='arch'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/erikaMlejova_malta.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/erikaMlejova_malta.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/architecture/antonelloMastinu_italy.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='arch'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/antonelloMastinu_italy.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/antonelloMastinu_italy.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/chibi_rabbit.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/chibi_rabbit.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/chibi_rabbit.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/landscape/vaughanBourke_skyline.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/vaughanBourke_skyline.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/vaughanBourke_skyline.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/danielSteger_deers.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/danielSteger_deers.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/danielSteger_deers.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/landscape/adrianvanLeen_cars.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/adrianvanLeen_cars.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/adrianvanLeen_cars.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/landscape/stuartMaxwell_desert.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/stuartMaxwell_desert.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/stuartMaxwell_desert.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/landscape/michaelJastremski_autum.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/michaelJastremski_autum.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/michaelJastremski_autum.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/stuartMaxwell_cheeta.JPG' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/stuartMaxwell_cheeta.JPG' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/stuartMaxwell_cheeta.JPG' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/sarahKlockars_moth.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/sarahKlockars_moth.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/sarahKlockars_moth.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/landscape/erikaMlejova_green.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='land'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/erikaMlejova_green.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/erikaMlejova_green.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/marekNovotny_puppy.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/marekNovotny_puppy.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/marekNovotny_puppy.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/architecture/michJastremski_penetentiary.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='arch'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/michJastremski_penetentiary.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/michJastremski_penetentiary.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/architecture/emmanuelSale_gotic.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='arch'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/emmanuelSale_gotic.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/emmanuelSale_gotic.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/meerkat.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/meerkat.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/meerkat.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/architecture/lorenteJerome_barcelona2.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='arch'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/lorenteJerome_barcelona2.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/lorenteJerome_barcelona2.jpg' /></a>
    <a class='fancybox imgContainer' href='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/animals/derekKeats_zimbabwe.jpg' data-fancybox-group='gallery' data-filter='anim'><img src='http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/derekKeats_zimbabwe.jpg' alt='image http://www.picssel.com/demos/gallery/thumbs/derekKeats_zimbabwe.jpg' /></a>
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
<!--wrap-->
```

Comment: i think the problem not in the function itself but its in the code as if you check the line which is written
// set data-fancybox-group and show filtered elements. 
 you will find its fading in the selected elements i think what we need to add a function to fade out others. @JFK

Comment: i have already did  that from the beginning what i want to know is for example -referring to the demo- if i click on animals it will show the category animal but will only decrease the opacity of other categories at the same page and not fade them out ...... the problem also that i am not good in coding but i think we should create a variable its name is $other for example which is not equal to $filter and then at if statement we should write function `.attr("$other") .Fade To()` but of corse i am not sure of that coz am not good enough in coding. i appreciate your help

Comment: Is my example not what you are after? Non matched items are partially faded as you asked for.

Comment: its exactly the same what i am looking for but i just want to add one feature which is:
when i select a specific category (e.g. animal) it will show this category as faded in and other categories(e.g. landscape, architectural) will not faded out (disappear) but will will have lower opacity only

Comment: Isnt that what im doing? What browser are you using? When you run my snippet on osx chrome you get full opacity on the selected category and 0.2 on the others

Comment: if you try to press view all again after choosing any category it won't work it will remain the same

Comment: @paulrf, updated, figured it may be a teach a man to fish deal :)

Comment: @ haxxxton you are brilliant .... its solved but i have two problems i wish you can help me with it...
1- its not working with chrome and internet explorer browsers but its working with Firefox browser.
2- when i minimize the screen the shape of the gallery changed and i want to keep it responsive with the size of the window can you tell me how? .
finally i would thank you for your patience and help you helped a beginner and i appreciate that

Comment: @paulrf, have you used [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) before? it is a great tool for controlling the number of items across the page based on screen breakpoints (ie. 2 across on mobile, 4 across on tablet, etc.). It is working for me on OSX Chrome (I am using a Mac, so cannot test Internet Explorer for you). Is it throwing errors? what is not working?

Comment: i used your code exactly and its working perfectly on all browsers(chrome firefox and internet explorer) but when i tried mine its only working on firefox and i don't know the reason really as its confusing me also i have no errors and here i uploaded the code so you can see that there is no difference

Comment: also i have used bootstrap and i know it as i am working on Dreamweaver so its included there already but the problem i should include a css @media but i don't know what to do for it  but i will search and try to solve it

Comment: @paulrf, can you deploy your code somewhere so that all the links to your images, css and js files work please. I can see you're including jQuery twice. I am assuming you want all your images to be the same size right? if so, you should put them _all_ in a single `.row` and then give them _all_ the same set of bootstrap grid classes (eg. `.col-xs-6`, `.col-md-4`, `.col-lg-2`). Then remove all the height and width styles you've added inline

Comment: good morning ... i wish you havent lost hope with me yet.. for the images i want it in a specific pattern [1][Picture]

Comment: good morning ... i wish you havent lost hope with me yet.. for the images i want it in a specific pattern https://imageshack.com/i/pnSqT8Vqp  but when i minimize i got the pattern disturbed as shown here in this https://imageshack.com/i/pmrLtIhyj
i think it depends on @media in Css but i dont know how to use

Comment: @paulrf, can you start a new question specifically for the media queries, as this is a very different issue from the original one. I am happy to help you when you get that up and running though. In the meantime, please consider marking this as solved

Comment: i want to mark as solved but they are telling me that i should have 15 reputation